# QuickFixJ FIXT.1.1 : Sending MarketPriceIncrementalRefresh to Bloomberg

Tags: java, bloomberg, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm having trouble sending packets of type X to Bloomberg. I want to send packets to create/update the price of fixed income securities using their CUSIP. I'm creating the FIX 5.0 Sp2 MarketDataIncrementalRefresh but I don't see how I can integrate my bid/offer prices into it.

Here's my sample code :

```
MarketDataIncrementalRefresh marketDataIncrementalRefresh = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh();
MDIncGrp mdIncGrp = new MDIncGrp();
mdIncGrp.set(new NoMDEntries(2));
NoMDEntryTypes mdEntryTypes = new NoMDEntryTypes();
mdEntryTypes.setValue('0');
```

I saw there were MDIncGrp, NoMDEntries, NoMDEntryTypes requirements yet I cannot see how prices are inputted with these !
Can someone help me with this issue or provide examples on how to implement this type of messages with FIXT.1.1? I saw many examples related to older versions of FIX but they don't seem to be compatible. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518553/how-do-you-get-repeating-groups-in-a-quickfixj-message  but instead of getting the group you need to add it to the message.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll check it out !

Comment: And also https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/repeating_groups.html is very close to what you want to do.

Comment: Both link you provided were very helpful ! Many thanks

Comment: I was able to post prices in the correct format